# Unable to access the whole payload structure in flowVars

Tags: variables, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, x12

I have a X12 file in which I have Batch Number at BHT03 which I need to put in flowVars. When I am trying to set it in a flow variable I am able to access the payload till 837 tree structure. The structure from Heading onwards doesnt appear when I enter a dot after "837". Even after writing the path manually it fetches null. Is there any constraint that we cannot set value in flowvars with tree structure?

The structure/path is as follows: (want to set the below value in flow vars)

```
#[payload.TransactionSets.v005010."837".Heading.0100_BHT.BHT03]
```

Able to set the flowvars value as below:

```
#[payload.TransactionSets.v005010.837]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
#[message.payload.'TransactionSets'.'v005010'.'837'.'Heading'.'0100_BHT'.'BHT03']
```